# Setting up Raspberry Pi Pico ("No module named 'Machine'")

Tags: pycharm, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to set up a [Raspberry Pi Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Raspberry_Pi_Pico) for the first time.  I've got [MicroPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroPython) installed, and got my environment set up in [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs).  I wrote a simple program to test my setup, and I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\...\Blink.py", line 1, in <module>
    from machine import Pin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'
```

Here's the code:

```
from machine import Pin
import time

led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
while True:
    led(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    led(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I've found other questions where people had a similar problem when using an [ESP32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32), but how can I handle this in PyCharm with a Pi Pico?

Comment: The `machine` module is only available when running micropython code *on the Pico*. I'm not familiar with Pycharm, but are you certain it isn't just trying to run your code with regular Python on your development machine?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain.  I'm following a tutorial on YouTube, and the process worked for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you are running the code in the Raspberry Pi Pico, not in your computer.

Use the [Thonny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thonny) IDE, because you can easily run and save the code in the Raspberry Pi Pico [link to download the Thonny IDE](https://thonny.org/)
and then use [this link](https://core-electronics.com.au/guides/how-to-setup-a-raspberry-pi-pico-and-code-with-thonny/) to know how to set up this IDE to run the code on the Raspberry Pi Pico.

Answer (score 0):

When I make a new project and try to run using the green arrow at the top right of PyCharm, I get this message.  But if I right-click my source code in the project tree and choose "Run Flash ...", it starts working.